# Disable UIPanGestureRecognizer in certain views of navigation controller

Tags: swift, controller, navigation, swipe, gesture

I have a navigation controller that contains a central, left and right view controller. A `UIPanGestureRecognizer` is added to all of them. Now, I want to add another view to the central view controller via a segue, but the swipe animation is added there too. How can I make this extra view controller static?

The swipe gestures are from this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/78568/create-slide-out-navigation-panel-swift

Answer (score 0):

You may add some kind of UIButton inside this view that will disable your gestureRecognizer on Touch Down and enable it on releasing your finger (Touch Up Inside and Drag Exit).

This should do the trick.